# Recursively delete files with 'WIDTHxLENGTH' in the name in a directory

Tags: shell, files, regular-expression, wildcards

I have a directory that has subdirectories, and I want to delete images named like `thumbnail-name_WIDTHxLENGTH.{jpg,png}`, where `WIDTH` and `LENGTH` are both decimal integers, like `box-image-150x150.jpg` and `circle-image-320x320.png`. So basically it's any jpg/png that contains an `x` surrounded by digits.

Comment: Can you give some examples? Are width and length always (and only) digits? What can `name` contain?

Comment: For example box-image-150x150.jpg and circle-image-320x320.png so basically any jpg/png that contains numbers with an x in the middle example 567x876

Answer (score 2):

```
# Old school way for directory-walking: find (emacs regex; use `(jpg|png)` on BSD find)
# use -iregex for case-insensitive
find some/dir -regex '.*[0-9]+x[0-9]+.\(jpg\|png\)' -delete
# ksh93, zsh & bash: globstar + brace expansion + extglob
# for ksh, use `set -o globstar` first; for bash, use `shopt -s globstar extglob nullglob` first.
# TODO: Too lazy to write zsh cshnullglob and case-insensitive globs
rm -- **/*[0-9]x+([0-9]).{jpg,png}
```

Comment: `-delete` is not standard and so might not work on all POSIX-compliant systems.

Answer (score 1):

The term “regular expression” (generally) doesn’t apply
to selecting files from the command line.<sup>1</sup> 
The technical term is pathname expansion,
more commonly known as globbing, pattern matching, or wildcard expansion. 
Based on what you have said, a first attempt at an answer would be

```
rm -- *[0-9]x[0-9]*
```

which removes every file in the current directory whose name consists of

- anything (`*`), followed by
- a digit (`[0-9]`), followed by
- the letter `x`, followed by
- another a digit (`[0-9]`), followed by
- anything (`*`).

The `--` protects you against files whose names begin with `-`. 
I strongly urge you to do

```
ls -ld -- *[0-9]x[0-9]*
```

first, to see what files are matched and will be removed. 
If you discover that you’re matching files that you didn’t mean to,
use `*[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9]*` to get only files that contain
(at least) a three-digit number, `x`, and another three-digit number. 
And/or append `.jpg` (at the end; i.e., use `*[0-9]x[0-9]*.jpg`)
to restrict the command to files with that extension,
and then repeat the command with `.png`. 
Alternatively, use

```
rm -i -- *[0-9]x[0-9]*
```

to have `rm` ask you for confirmation for each file.

You mentioned “a directory that has directories. All of them have jpgs.” 
If you need to search a directory tree, one approach is to type

```
shopt -u globstar
```

and then prepend `**/` to the wildcard; i.e., add it at the beginning; e.g.,

```
rm -i -- **/*[0-9]x[0-9]*
```

Yet another way to scan a subdirectory tree is

```
find . -name "*[0-9]x[0-9]*" -type f -exec rm -i -- {} +
```

and you can “preview” this command (see what files it will match) by typing

```
find . -name "*[0-9]x[0-9]*" -type f -print
```

Again, if this matches too many files,
you can add digits and/or add the extension(s).

Notes:

- You must quote the wildcard in the `find` command. 
  You must not quote the wildcard in the other commands.
- The `find` command will automatically find files whose names begin
  with **`.`**. 
  The others will not, unless you type `shopt -s dotglob` first.
- The `find` command will act on plain files only, because of the `-type f`. 
  The others will act on directories (and other special files)
  if their name contains `numberxnumber`. 
  This shouldn’t be a problem for directories,
  since `rm` will not remove directories. 
  But, as I said, do the `ls` first and carefully check the output,
  or use `rm -i` and think before you type `y`.

_________
<sup>1</sup> `find` does have the ability to match regular expressions,
with the `-regex` test, but you don’t need it for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use find with xargs:

```
find / -name "*[0-9]*x*[0-9]*.jpg" | xargs /bin/rm -f
```

EDIT:

```
find / -name "*[0-9]x[0-9]*.jpg" | xargs /bin/rm -f
```

or like 'authur2e5' suggested in the comments below:

```
find some/dir -name "*[0-9]x[0-9]*.jpg" -delete
```

Comment: `find some/dir -name "*[0-9]x[0-9]*.jpg" -delete`

Comment: @Arthur2e5 - I believe the way you wrote it will only look for a single number and not something like 150 (*edit*: I was wrong...the asterisk before it will catch the other numbers), but essentially that is another correct.way. I prefer xargs to -delete myself but it's all about personal preference.

Comment: You are confused. If you want regex / Kleene astericks, use `-regex '.*[0-9]+x[0-9]+.jpg'`.

Comment: And using `-delete` is a bit faster and much safer (not important here).

Comment: You are correct. I edited my comment. :)

Comment: Your first answer will choke on filenames containing whitespace and other special characters; you should use `find … -print0` and `xargs -0`.  And you probably shouldn’t start searching from the system root directory.  While `-delete` may be infinitesimally faster than the other approaches, it is not standard and so might not work on all POSIX-compliant systems.

Comment: @G-Man I think `xargs -0` is an extension too.

Comment: Touché.  I did not know that.